# How do I make my JavaScript function stop after finding the first parent with a certain class?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I'm currently making a Drag-and-Drop engine in JavaScript. I'm currently working on making "bounds" for some "drag-able" objects. A drag-object has bounds if its parent (or a parent of a parent ect.) has the class `.bound`. The function I am using to find out if the drag-object is bounded is (Yes, this function also creates the drag-object.):

```
function makeObj(e) {
    obj = new Object();
    obj.element = e;

    obj.boundX = e.parentNode.offsetWidth - e.offsetWidth;
    obj.boundY = e.parentNode.offsetHeight - e.offsetHeight;

    obj.posX = event.clientX - e.offsetLeft;
    obj.posY = event.clientY - e.offsetTop;

    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (e.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += e.offsetLeft;
            curtop += e.offsetTop;
            //alert(e.id + ":" + e.innerHTML);
            if(~e.className.search(/bound/)) {
                obj.boundX = curleft - obj.element.offsetLeft;
                obj.boundY = curtop - obj.element.offsetTop;
                return obj;
            }

        } while (e = e.offsetParent);
    }

    return obj;
}
```

For clarification: This function MAKES the drag-object. My problem lies in the loops. The loops don't find the first parent node with a `.bound` class.

This html "should" affect the function:

```
<div id="center" class="bound">
    <h1>Hello World! <hr /></h1>
    <div id="box" class="bound">
        <p class="drag square" id="one"> One </p>
        <p class="drag square" id="two"> Two </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As much as this html:

```
<div id="center"> <!-- Difference is here -->
    <h1>Hello World! <hr /></h1>
    <div id="box" class="bound">
        <p class="drag square" id="one"> One </p>
        <p class="drag square" id="two"> Two </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the first html affects the loops (and how the drag objects behave), and I don't know why.

P.S. The function is slightly broken. I haven't managed to set the "correct" value for `obj.boundX` and `obj.boundY` without using this inferior (because it makes the parentNode the bound element regardless of class) function:

```
function makeBoundlessObj(e) {
    obj = new Object();
    obj.element = e;

    obj.boundX = e.parentNode.offsetWidth - e.offsetWidth;
    obj.boundY = e.parentNode.offsetHeight - e.offsetHeight;

    obj.posX = event.clientX - e.offsetLeft;
    obj.posY = event.clientY - e.offsetTop;

    return obj;
}
```

I will post the entire engine below (and a jsfiddle link) just in case it is useful:

http://jsfiddle.net/Upvdm/1/

```
// JavaScript Document

var dragObj;

document.addEventListener("mousedown", down, false);

function down(event) {
    if(~event.target.className.search(/drag/)) {
        dragObj = makeObj(event.target);
        dragObj.element.style.zIndex="100";
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", freeMovement, false);
    }
}

function freeMovement(event) {

    if (typeof(dragObj.element.mouseup) == "undefined")
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
    //Prevents redundantly adding the same event handler repeatedly

dragObj.element.style.left = Math.max(0, Math.min(event.clientX - dragObj.posX, dragObj.boundX)) + "px";
    dragObj.element.style.top = Math.max(0, Math.min(event.clientY - dragObj.posY, dragObj.boundY)) + "px";
}

function drop() {
    dragObj.element.style.zIndex="1";

    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", freeMovement, false);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
    //alert("DEBUG_DROP");
}

function makeBoundlessObj(e) {
    obj = new Object();
    obj.element = e;

    obj.boundX = e.parentNode.offsetWidth - e.offsetWidth;
    obj.boundY = e.parentNode.offsetHeight - e.offsetHeight;

    obj.posX = event.clientX - e.offsetLeft;
    obj.posY = event.clientY - e.offsetTop;

    return obj;
}

function makeObj(e) {
    obj = new Object();
    obj.element = e;

    obj.boundX = e.parentNode.offsetWidth - e.offsetWidth;
    obj.boundY = e.parentNode.offsetHeight - e.offsetHeight;

    obj.posX = event.clientX - e.offsetLeft;
    obj.posY = event.clientY - e.offsetTop;

    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (e.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += e.offsetLeft;
            curtop += e.offsetTop;
            //alert(e.id + ":" + e.innerHTML);
            if(~e.className.search(/bound/)) {
                obj.boundX = curleft - obj.element.offsetLeft;
                obj.boundY = curtop - obj.element.offsetTop;
                return obj;
            }

        } while (e = e.offsetParent);
    }

    return obj;
}

function findPos(obj) { // Donated by `lwburk` on StackOverflow
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
    }
}
```

In case the problem was not clear:
My JavaScript function `makeObj()` isn't setting the correct `boundX` and `boundY` because elements with the class `.bound` are affecting the function when they shouldn't be.

Thank you all for reading and helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the loop is functioning as you desire. It *is* finding the first element tagged with the `bound` class. The problem you're seeing is related to the `position:relative` that comes along with the `bound` class.

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div id="center" style="position:relative">
    <h1>Hello World! <hr /></h1>
    <div id="box" class="bound" >
        <p class="drag square" id="one"> One </p>
        <p class="drag square" id="two"> Two </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It functions identically to your "first" HTML (the one where center is tagged with the `bound` class).

The important thing here is that tagging an element with `position:relative` or `position:absolute` makes the child elements see its upper left corner as `(0,0)`. In CSS, child elements look up to their first ancestor that is tagged with a relative or absolute position. Elements that are not tagged as such are not seen by the child as having an upper left corner at `(0,0)`.

The trouble here is that you're using the `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` of the desired bound (the nearest ancestor with the `bound` class; in this case `box`), which varies when that element's nearest ancestor tagged with relative/absolute changes. In the first case, the nearest positioned ancestor is `center`... in the second case it's the document. In the first case `makeObj` returns (0, 22). In the second it returns (108,82).

Unless you're doing this as an academic exercise or a fun project, consider just using an existing DnD library like the one that comes with Dojo: http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/dnd

Comment: That explains it. Thank you so much. I am indeed doing an academic project. This is my first week of JavaScript and there is no better way to learn a language than by making things =]

Comment: In that case, I might also suggest being careful about your use of global variables. In your `makeObj` and `makeBoundlessObj` functions you create a new global `obj`. Instead you should declare obj with the `var` keyword to make it local to the function (JavaScript is dumb that way... it just makes globals for all the non-`var` declared variables). If you have the time, you should also check out Douglas Crockford's talks on JS: http://yuiblog.com/crockford/

Comment: thanks, I will make it local, and I'll check out those talks!